How can I set up a site from config or from clean database dump for PHPUnit?
Does anyone have any suggestions or examples on how to set up a Drupal Site from config or from clean database dump (say mysite_dump.sql.gz) for PHPUnit tests?
I don't want to run tests against a database which has content, but I want a clean site with all the configurations imported to run tests.
Seems fixtures can help me with my requirements. But it is not working as expected. I am not able to get the desired site from the setup.
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function setDatabaseDumpFiles() {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList $extension_list */
  $extension_list = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module');

  $this->databaseDumpFiles = $extension_list->getPath('mysite_tests') . '/tests/fixtures/update/mysite_database_clean.php.gz';

  // $this->databaseDumpFiles = [
  //   __DIR__ . '/../../../tests/fixtures/update/mysite_dump.sql.gz',
  // ];
}

I have created mysite_database_clean.php.gz using the guide from Writing Automated Update Tests for Drupal 8 (or later) / Creating your own dump and mysite_dump.sql.gz using drush sql:dump.
I also tried using Drupal Test Traits, but it creates entities while running tests; if the test fails, it does not remove all the created entities.
Drupal Test Traits is suitable for my use case, but orphaned entities are something I don't want after test failures.
Tests are my own tests so I can create logic to delete entities on tearDown(), but they are only practical when I create entities via code in tests; cleanup of entities is not always possible when they are created with form submission in tests, which is major deal breaker for orphaned entities cleanup.
Every failed DTT test changes database state which is not a good case for testing.
My Sample LoadTest.

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Drupal\Tests\mysite_tests\Functional;

use Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase;
use Drupal\FunctionalTests\Update\UpdatePathTestBase;
use Drupal\Tests\UpdatePathTestTrait;

/**
 * Class to Test vanilla site.
 *
 * @group mysite_tests
 */
final class LoadTest extends BrowserTestBase {

  use UpdatePathTestTrait;

  /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  protected $defaultTheme = 'mysite_theme';


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected static $modules = ['mysite_tests'];

  /**
   * The file path(s) to the dumped database(s) to load into the child site.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $databaseDumpFiles = [];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setDatabaseDumpFiles() {

    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList $extension_list */
    $extension_list = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module');

    $this->databaseDumpFiles = $extension_list->getPath('mysite_tests') . '/tests/fixtures/update/mysite_database_clean.php.gz';

    // $this->databaseDumpFiles = [
    //   __DIR__ . '/../../../tests/fixtures/update/mysite_dump.sql.gz',
    // ];

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp(): void {
    parent::setUp();
    // Set up the test here.
  }

  /**
   * Test callback.
   */
  public function testSomething(): void {
    $adminUser = $this->drupalCreateUser();
    $adminUser->addRole($this->createAdminRole('admin', 'admin'));
    $adminUser->save();
    $this->drupalLogin($adminUser);

    $this->runUpdates();
    
    $this->drupalGet('admin');
    $this->assertSession()->elementExists('xpath', '//h1[text() = "Administration"]');
  }

}


It seems like what you want is what DTT does, but you don't like what DTT does in case of failure?  What is the source of these tests?  If they are your own tests, you can just write a cleanup function to do whatever you want.

Yes, DTT is suitable for my use case but orphaned entities is something that I dont want after test failures.
Tests are my own tests. I can create logic to delete entities on Teardown but they are only practical when I create entites via code in tests, cleanup of entities is not always possible when they are created with form submit in tests. Which is major deal breaker for orphaned entities cleanup.

And also every failed DTT test changes database state which is not a good case for testing.

You can delete the entities with drush or entityQuery.  I understand it's a pain point when a failed test changes the db state and breaks subsequent tests; I have the same issue with behat.  One way I addressed this was to break up the tests into separate test suites and run the various suites using a batch script. The bash script uses drush to run a php script to reset everything in between the tests.  It takes longer this way but then all the data is ready for me when I'm ready to debug.

Seems DTT is the best way for now. Maybe we can have some more efficient testing methods. :(
